# How do I make my build file depend on another build file being run first?

Tags: java, ant

I have a build file that depends on a jar file located in another project. However, there is an overarching build file that is used to build all the projects at once and I cannot be guaranteed that the other project will be built before mine (in which case my project will fail). I was wondering if there was a way to ensure that the other project will be built before mine is called `without having to use Ivy` (saw the other topic on this).

Right now I have a target in my ant script where I call the `ant` task on the build files of the projects I depend on and that's working fine (or at least appears to be)

The layout is like this:

```
  <target name="buildDependencies">
        <ant antfile="../some_project/build.xml" target="build" inheritAll="false" dir="../some_project"/>
        <ant antfile="../someOtherProjectIDependOn/build.xml" target="build" inheritAll="false" dir="../someOtherProjectIDependOn"/>
    </target>

  <target name="build" depends="buildDependencies">
  //other projects are guaranteed to be built so go ahead and build this project's stuff
  </target>
```

but I am wondering if this is somehow dangerous or if it'll cause that overarching build file (that calls all projects to be built) to essentially build the projects in `buildDependencies` twice.

I was hoping that there was a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: You could put `ant` down, wash your hands thoroughly, then pick up [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and be a Grownup. This is **exactly** what `Maven` is all about.

Comment: I haven't written enough Ant (though I've maintained it -- or Maven, I'm not absolutely sure which), but I presume that as in Make the answer is essentially what you've done -- depend upon the results of the previous step rather than on its execution per se. In Make, you'd set up the dependency so that the target was built if its output was absent or if the input dependencies were newer than the output.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I wish I could but unfortunately this is not a personal project :(